# Does event.stopPropagation in a checkbox click event prevent the change event from firing in IE8 and earlier?

Tags: javascript, jquery

It appears that `event.stopPropagation()` in a checkbox `click` event prevents the associated `change` event from firing in IE before IE9.

(The following code is in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UftSd/))

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Y" checked>Test
<div id="output">Logging...</div>
```

With the following jquery block the change event *doesn't* fire in IE8 and earlier but it *does* fire in IE9 (and Chrome):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("input").click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $("#output").append("<pre>click</pre>");
    });

    $("input").change(function(event) {
        $("#output").append("<pre>change</pre>");
    });

});
```

Chrome and IE9 give:

```
Logging...
change
click
change
click
change
click
```

Whereas IE8 and earlier gives:

```
Logging...
click
click
click
```

However, if I put specific 'before IE9' handling then all works as expected:

With the following jquery block:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("input").click(function(event) {

        event.stopPropagation();

        $("#output").append("<pre>click</pre>");

        // fix event bubbling before IE9
        if ($.browser.msie) {
            if (parseInt($.browser.version, 10) < 9) {
                $(this).trigger("change");
            }
        }

    });

    $("input").change(function(event) {
        $("#output").append("<pre>change</pre>");
    });

});
```

Is this expected behaviour?

Comment: Expected? No. Though I'm honestly not surprised that earlier versions of IE do something that seems so absurd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Compiling the comments on Tgr's answer so I can accept an answer.)

If the "event.stopPropagation()" line is removed from the click event the change event is fired as expected in IE8, so this isn't the well-known IE8 bug [mentioned by Tgr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9688387/4003).

@Tgr confirmed that:

> jQuery tries to normalize most browser quirks, including this one: it simulates a change event on click and eats the one fired on blur (see `jQuery.event.special.change`). `stopPropagation` probably interferes with that.

Answer (score 3):

This is a [well-known IE8 bug](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/change.html#t04) which has nothing to do with event bubbling: the change event only fires on checkboxes when the focus leaves them.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, if the "event.stopPropagation()" line is removed from the click event the change event is fired as expected in IE8.

Comment: So... I don't believe this is the well-known IE8 bug as the test case I provided works fine when the "event.stopPropagation()" line is removed.

Comment: jQuery tries to normalize most browser quirks, including this one: it simulates a change event on click and eats the one fired on blur (see `jQuery.event.special.change`). `stopPropagation` probably interferes with that.

Comment: In which case, this sounds like a jquery since stopPropagation is supposed to prevent events bubbling up to parents, not to prevent events within the given element.

Comment: I think these comments contain the correct answer - I've compiled in a separate answer (and upvoted @Tgr's answer).